# Exact way to Isometric Embed a Riemannian manifold into Euclidean Space

Tags: differential-geometry

I learnt from the Nash Embedding theorem that every Riemannian manifold can be isometrically embedded into some Euclidean space. But is there some pratical way to construct the embedding?
A toy example, suppose the metric of the manifold is g=m*diag(3), where m varies over the manifold. How to embed it into Euclidean space

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Nash's theorem is a hard existence theorem for a solution of some nonlinear PDE. Typically, there is no way to "practically construct" a solution whatever you mean by this. One can find approximate solutions but that's all. Two more things: (1) You should use MathJax to write main in your questions. (2) Metrics that you tried to describe are called *conformally flat*.

Comment: Maybe not a duplicate, but related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4780961/alternate-definition-of-riemannian-manifold